# Bitbucket recent activities - Repo activity is currently unavailable

Tags: git, bitbucket

On each repository Overwiev, that I enter on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org), I get:

> **Recent activity**
>
> Repo activity is currently unavailable.

Has anybody clue what is happening?

Two my colleagues have the same problem. We check on Ubuntu 16.04, Win 10 and Mac iOS 10.12.4.

*Update 2017-04-19:*
Problem still appears.

Solution answer from [@Zhenya Telegin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7887530/zhenya-telegin) works only for history of last commits.
But **Recent activity** Overview should shows:

- create/update on pull requests
- create/update task
- code comments

That way is important for me and my team.

*Update 2017-04-20:* Problem was noticed by Atlassian Bitbucket Team.

**They fixed problem with [this ticket](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14156/recent-activity-not-updating)**

Thank you once again.

Comment: It appears to be a larger-scale issue. It's not working here as well.

Comment: is this happening again. Just getting the same message for the past 30min on all my repos

Comment: This can be connected to overall `Degraded performance` by bitbucket - https://status.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're working on resolving this. Watch this issue for updates: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14156/recent-activity-not-updating

Pushing/pulling should not be affected.

Thanks!

Alastair
Atlassian Bitbucket

Comment: It is working again. Thank you. I assume that this issue was somehow correlated to changing [price system](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing/upcoming)

Comment: @alwilkes is this happening again? I am getting these messages on all my repositories for the past 30min

Comment: @zabumba same issue with me as well, I can push to bitbucket though! did you find any resolutions?

Comment: Not resolved, but to remove my blocker, I added a remote using HTTPS instead of GIT `git add remote bitbucket https://myid@bitbucket.org/blahablah/myrepo.git` and the `git pull` worked

Answer (score 4):

I also stuck with this, but it works when you manually open commits page

```
https://bitbucket.org/REPO_AUTHOR/REPO_NAME/commits/all
```

:)

Comment: What do you mean: **manually open commits page** - do you mean click on Commits link?

Even that you will see only history of last commits - **None** of create/update on pull requests and task or even code comments -> which you can see on Recent activity ion Overview.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem on Bitbucket's side. About 11.30pm EST on 17th April, it would not let me push/commit. About 3-4 minutes later, I was able to commit and push my repository but the recent repository activity was unavailable. It would however show the last time I made changes in the repository overview tab. If you need to view commits,  the Commits option on the left pane still works fine. It's over 15 hours and this issue still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: For issue you talked about (push/fetch/pull from origin), I always check [status platform](https://status.bitbucket.org/). Unfortunately for my issue it is not give any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue since 10 am CST, however, as of right now, 'repo activity' is displaying or selected repo's/projects but rss feed on all activity still displays ..unavailable.

Comment: And it's down again.